# Telnet over ssh tunnel in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, telnet, ssh-tunnel

server('10.42.102.11') ←————→ device('192.168.253.205')

↑

|

SSH(22)

|

↓

localhost (me)

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('10.42.102.11', 22),
        ssh_username="serv_usr",
        ssh_password="serv_pass",
        remote_bind_address=('192.168.253.205', 2323),
) as tunnel:
    telnet = Telnet()
    #telnet.open('127.0.0.1', 2323)
    telnet.open('192.168.253.205', 2323)
    telnet.close()
```

That results:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 227, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

I cannot find what I am doing wring here (manually connection works well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you forward ports you generally connect to a local address that is forwarded to a remote service. Here you're trying to connect to `192.168.253.205` which is not reachable (and isn't made reachable by the tunnel alone). I think the piece you're missing is the `local_bind_address` to give you the local port to connect to.

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('10.42.102.11', 22),
    ssh_username="serv_usr",
    ssh_password="serv_pass",
    remote_bind_address=('192.168.253.205', 2323),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 10022)
```

This should allow you to connect to the local port 10022 (or whatever available port you choose) which will be forwarded to 2323 on the remote machine:

```
telnet.open('127.0.0.1', 10022)
```

Comment: I've changed my code to your tips and got such error:

`2017-10-10 16:46:55,142| ERROR   | Could not establish connection from ('127.0.0.1', 10022) to remote side of the tunnel
ERROR:sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder:Could not establish connection from ('127.0.0.1', 10022) to remote side of the tunnel`

Comment: well I guess that’s an improvement over a timeout. You should make sure all the numbers are correct - if you open an ssh session to the server can you hit the 192.168.253.205 on port 2323?

Comment: At last, your solution worked, there was an issue not related to topic, that i could not connect. Thank you very much for your help! :)